# Training an autoregressive model using multiple independent sequences

Tags: markov-process, gaussian-process, autoregressive

I have a number of independent observed sequences that I believe are generated by same underlying process.
Is it possible to extend linear autoregression and learn the optimal transition matrix for multiple sequences?
I'll explain my approach.

I'll start with autoregression for a single sequence.
I observe a sequence of vectors $\mathbf{x}_{0:K} \triangleq \mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{x}_{1}, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{K}$.
I assume the temporal evolution of $\mathbf{x}_{k}$ is defined by
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_{k} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{k-1} + \boldsymbol{\eta}_{k},
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a time-invariant transition matrix, $\boldsymbol{\eta}_{k} \sim \mathcal{N} ( \cdot ; \, \mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ is zero-mean Gaussian noise with known covariance $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$.
I want to determine the optimal transition matrix $\mathbf{A}$ for this sequence.
I begin by writing the autoregressive model as the likelihood function:
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x}_{0:K} \, | \, \mathbf{A}) = p(\mathbf{x}_{0}) \prod_{k=1}^{K} p( \mathbf{x}_{k} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \mathbf{A} ),
\end{align}
where the Markov density is Gaussian,
$p( \mathbf{x}_{k} \, | \, \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \mathbf{A} ) = \mathcal{N} (\mathbf{x}_{k} ; \, \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}),$
as is the prior on first vector in the sequence,
$p(\mathbf{x}_{0}) = \mathcal{N} (\mathbf{x}_{0} ; \, \mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\Lambda}).$
Determining the transition matrix $\mathbf{A}$ that maximises the likelihood function is equivalent to minimising the negative log-likelihood
\begin{align}
L (\mathbf{A}) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{K} (\mathbf{x}_{k} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{k-1})^{T} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x}_{k} - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{k-1}) + \text{const},
\end{align}
and we obtain the closed-form solution of
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} = \bigg( \sum_{k=1}^{K} \mathbf{x}_{k} \mathbf{x}_{k-1}^{T} \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{k=1}^{K} \mathbf{x}_{k-1} \mathbf{x}_{k-1}^{T} \bigg)^{-1}.
\end{align}

Now, I observe a second sequence of vectors $\mathbf{y}_{0:J} \triangleq \mathbf{y}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{1}, \dots, \mathbf{y}_{J}$.
I again assume the sequence's time evolution is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}_{j} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}_{j-1} + \boldsymbol{\eta}_{j}.
\end{align}
Is the likelihood function I want to maximise now given by
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x}_{0:K}, \mathbf{y}_{0:J} \, | \, \mathbf{A}) = p(\mathbf{x}_{0:K} \, | \, \mathbf{A}) p(\mathbf{y}_{0:J} \, | \, \mathbf{A})?
\end{align}
Is this approach sensible?
What sort of prior distribution can we place on $\mathbf{A}$?
Are there better ways of learning transition matrices?

Comment: This seems reasonable. $x$ and $y$ are independent of each other I am assuming. And in maximum likelihood all you are doing is finding a $A$ matrix which is 'likely given your data', so calculating the joint probability as you have done makes sense. With respect to the prior that is a bit tricky, since you ideally want it to be a prior over $A$ matrices with maximum absolute eigenvalue less than 1 (for stationarity), so not sure the best way to do that.

Comment: @DavidVeitch, maximum likelihood is about finding an $A$ matrix which makes *the data* likely, not finding an $A$ matrix which is likely given the data.

Comment: @RichardHardy yes, that is a better way to say it; assuming the data arises from your model, maximum likelihood finds a $A$ so that the data observed is likely.

Comment: "What sort of prior can we place on ?" That is a domain specific question. In some contexts, the identity matrix might be a reasonable first guess.  In other contexts, where x represents {position, velocity, acceleration}, your knowledge of physics would guide an initial guess for A.

Comment: @krkeane Good point, but to clarify things and be more specific: What sort of prior distribution can we place on a matrix-valued random variable (RV)? If the RV were vector-valued, then we'd be able place a Gaussian distribution on the RV, where the Gaussian's parameters are specified by the domain.

Comment: @scj - see: Dawid, A. Philip. "Some matrix-variate distribution theory: notational considerations and a Bayesian application." Biometrika 68.1 (1981): 265-274.

Comment: @krkeane After giving this a very light read, it seems many of these distributions assume the matrix is at least symmetric positive semi-definite. However, here $\mathbf{A}$ is only required to be square. Could we sidestep this problem by vectorising $\mathbf{A}$? We have the column vector $\mathbf{y}_{k-1} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{k-1}$, so we rewrite it as $\mathbf{y}_{k-1} = ( \mathbf{x}_{k-1}^{T} \otimes \mathbf{I} ) \mathbf{a}$, where $\mathbf{a} = \text{vec} (\mathbf{A})$. Does this fundamentally change anything? Hopefully it doesn't, and we can place a Gaussian prior on $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: If $A$ has eigenvalues greater than 1 then this process is explosive (which we do not want). My guess is the 'correct' prior is to look at sparse $A$ matrices with nonzero values along diagonal and sparse off-diagonal entries. If either the row or column sums are all less than 1 then it will have eigenvalues less than 1.